# how to get nickname by user id

Tags: discord, discord.js

i'm making a simple discord bot with discord.js, but i got a problem getting user nickname.

I'm making Coin-system, so I'm using a dictionary like this;

```
Coin = {
"User1 id" : User1 coin (int),
"User2 id" : User2 coin (int),

"User3 id" : User3 coin (int) }
```

And I'm trying to make rank command,
So I have to get the user's sever nickname with user id.

But I cant find how to.
Plz tell me how to get nickname by user id

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet shows how to get the nickname of a user by their ID

```
const guildMember = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId).members.cache.get(userId);

if (guildMember) {
  const nickname = guildMember.nickname;
} else {
  console.log('User not found');
}
```

The `guildMember` variable will be a `GuildMember` object, which has a `nickname` property that contains the user's nickname in the guild. If the user does not have a nickname, the `nickname` property will be `null`.

For example, if the user ID is `1234567890`, the following code would print the user's nickname to the console:

```
const nickname = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId).members.cache.get('1234567890').nickname;

console.log(nickname);
```

If the user does not have a nickname, the following code would print `null` to the console:

```
const nickname = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId).members.cache.get('1234567890').nickname;

if (nickname) {
  console.log(nickname);
} else {
  console.log('User does not have a nickname');
}
```

Comment: a... i tried, but got err; 
ReferenceError: guildId is not defined